# calculate the numeric value of a name

Tags: python

I'm trying to write program that calculate the numeric value of a name

this what i wrote

```
name = input("Enter your full name:")
low = name.lower()
sum = 0
print ()
for ch in name :
    print(sum + ord(ch)-96)
```

the problem is when i entered a name for example  anna i got

the output would be

> 1
>
> 14
>
> 14
>
> 1

How can i get only the sum ? which is going to be in this case 30

Answer (score 4):

You have to update the `sum` variable everytime in the loop. Change your loop to:

```
for ch in name :
    sum += ord(ch)-96

print(sum)
```

You can also use [`sum()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function with generator expression:

```
>>> name='anna'
>>> sum(ord(ch) - 96 for ch in name)
30
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to change your sum variable. Do it like:

```
low = name.lower()
sum = 0
print ()
for ch in name :
    sum = sum + ord(ch)-96
print(sum)
```

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/
Please note, that uppercase letters start from index 65. You could do an 'if' check if the character is between 64 and 90, or between 96 and 122.

Comment: @Jurgis

The reason it is not working properly is because you did not use the lower case version of the name entered. You had stored this value in `low` but you never used it in the actual calculation

Answer (score 2):

`bytearray` lets us add the ascii values directly using `sum`. Then you need to subtract 96 for each character in the string

```
sum(bytearray(low)) - 96 * len(low)
```

This works about twice as fast as using ord() for each character on my computer even for short strings, and even better for long strings

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use `for ch in name` in the right place - use generator expression. It would be more pythonic than using a loop:

```
name = input("Enter your full name:")
low = name.lower()
print ()

print sum(ord(ch)-96 for ch in name)
```

You can also use [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), but it would be slower

```
print sum([ord(ch)-96 for ch in name])
```

Comment: The first code will not work because you have set `sum` to `0` on the third line. Also in python3, you need the `()` brackets to print anything

Comment: yeah thanks. and +1 goes to your answer for mentioning not overriding python functions

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid using python keywords as variables. In your code, you have set the keyword `sum` which is actually a function to the value 0

Second, observe that you are in a for-loop so there is nothing to store the accumulating sum into as the for-loop progresses.

Here is what I came up with:

```
name = input("Enter your full name: ").lower() #Convert input to lowercase
print () #Print a newline
print (sum(ord(ch) - 96 for ch in name)) #Use the sum function to compute sum of letters
```

One-line:

```
print (sum(ord(ch) - 96 for ch in input("Enter your full name: ").lower()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for Python 3.

```
input_name = input("Enter Your Name: ").lower()

print(sum(ord(ch)-96 for ch in input_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I think solution from @gnibbler is the best.

Still, I want to share my idea. I would like use `map` rather than `for` loop or list comprehension:

```
name = input("Enter your full name:")
low = name.lower()
print sum(map(lambda ch: ord(ch)-96, low))
```